# "is my hair" or "are my hair" when I'm referring to all my head hair?

Tags: grammatical-number

What's more correct "is my hair" or "are my hair" when I'm referring to all my head hair? ("do my hair look bad" or "does my hair look bad" for example)

Thank you

Comment: What/where exactly is the question? *Hair **is***, *Hairs **are***.

Comment: This Q. is not about whether *hair* is singular or plural, because the OP's context is clear. Not a duplicate.

Comment: That's not a duplicate guys. I read the other question and it does not answer mine. Please remove the duplicate.

Comment: George, you may have to raise the point on meta I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

In the sentence

> Does my hair look bad?

*Hair* functions as a *mass noun*, meaning that it is uncountable. It refers to the collection of all the hairs (on your head, usually).

If you use a plural verb, you should also use a plural noun, so you should use *hairs*. You only do that if you are referring to individual strands of hair:

> I found two hairs in my soup.

Comment: So the answer is , I can't use plural and "hairs" in that context, even though grammatically it wouldn't be wrong.

Comment: Grammatically, it would be fine to ask if your **hairs** look bad. It just does not _mean_ the same as "does my hair look bad". If you ask about your _hairs_, people will be assuming you have an issue with specific strands of hair - they may think about hairs growing in places where you do not want them - ears, nose, whatever. More than grammar, idiom is important here. You want people to look at your _hairdo_? Use **hair**, not hairs :)